# CiviCRM 4.7.8 error after upgrade on eWay Recurring

Tags: payment-processor, error, eway

I have just upgraded from 4.6.18 to 4.7.8. The upgrade was successful but when I try to open CiviCRM menu items I get the following error:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'CRM/Core/Payment/Ewayrecurring.php'
>   (include_path='.:/var/www/test/sites/all/modules/civicrm:/var/www/test/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages:.:/var/www/test/sites/all/modules/civicrm:/var/www/test/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages:/var/www/test/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/var/www/test/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
>   in /var/www/test/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Payment/System.php on
>   line 59

I can't find reference to this anywhere. Has anyone else seen this issue?

When I reverted to CiviCRM 4.6.18 and then attempted to disable eWayRecurring I got this error:

I have reverted to Civicrm 4.6.18 and when I attempt to disable eWayRecurring extension I get the following error:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'CRM/Core/Payment/Ewayrecurring.php'
>   (include_path='/var/www/test/sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/com.pogstone.contenttokens/:/var/www/test/sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/com.cividesk.helptab/:/var/www/test/sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico-1.0-alpha4/:/var/www/test/sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/com.pesc.sparkpost-1.1/:/var/www/test/sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/coop.palantetech.nodrilldown-master/:/var/www/test/sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/:/var/www/test/sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/org.civicoop.membershippayment-master/:/var/www/test/sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/:.:/var/www/test/sites/all/modules/civicrm:/var/www/test/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages:.:/var/www/test/sites/all/modules/civicrm:/var/www/test/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages:/var/www/test/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/var/www/test/si
>   in /var/www/test/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Payment/System.php on
>   line 52

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards
Martin Fuggle

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you had at some point set up the [eWay Recurring extension](https://github.com/ChrisChinchilla/CiviCRM-eWay-recurring-payment-processor).  Looked at the list of paths, it doesn't seem to be installed currently.

I looked at line 59 in `Civi/Payment/System.php`, which your error references.  It seems like that function is running based on the payment processors you have configured.

The solution is to either:
a) Install the eWay Recurring extension it's 4.7-compatible); or
b) Go to **Administer menu » System Settings » Payment Processors** and delete your payment processor that uses eWay Recurring.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I reverted to CiviCRM 4.6.14 and was then able to disable the eWay recurring extension and uninstall it. I then upgraded to CiviCRM 4.6.18 without problem.

Comment: Glad to help Martin! Please help to make Stack Exchange more helpful to others by upvoting and marking as "accepted" answers that are helpful!

Comment: Certainly I will do what I can.