# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'CRM/Core/Payment/SDD.php'

Tags: configuration, payment

When I go to Configuration >> System Settings & URL >> Clear Cache and Update Paths
https://www.example.com/civicm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend?reset=1
I tried to reset path and I get a WSOD with the following error

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
 'CRM/Core/Payment/SDD.php'
 (include_path='.:/home/hob/www/lyme/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm:/home/hob/www/lyme/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/packages:.:/home/hob/www/lyme/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm:/home/hob/www/lyme/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/packages:/home/hob/www/lyme/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/home/hob/www/lyme/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:/home/hob/www/lyme/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/home/hob/www/lyme/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/vendor/pear/auth_sasl:/home/hob/www/lyme/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/vendor/pear/net_socket:/home/hob/www/lyme/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/vendor/pear/net_smtp:/home/hob/www/lyme/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/vendor/pear/validate_finance_creditcard:.:/usr/local/php56/lib/php')
 in
 /home/hob/www/lyme/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/Civi/Payment/System.php
 on line 59
```

I see a similar error listed out here : [CiviCRM 4.7.8 error after upgrade on eWay Recurring](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12721/civicrm-4-7-8-error-after-upgrade-on-eway-recurring)

Also when I checked the database for `civicrm_setting` table, I found all the values to be null.

[image]

When I looked into **CRM/Core/Payment/** folder, I did not find **SDD.php** 
is that an issue?

I went to the database and set all the payment processor.is_active = 0 .
I go back and Reset Paths and I get list of errors which are as given below
[image]

and last error on this list is this

```
Error loading module file (). Please restore the file or disable the module.
```

Comment: Did you change the extension path?

Comment: @PradeepNayak, currently extension path is at sites/all/modules/civicrm_extensions ? should I check it in the database? I have not changed it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have performed path reset than path of extension must have been updated and the system already have SDD payment processor created therefore it is throwing file not found error.

You can fix this in either of 3 ways:

1. If you have db access then update civicrm_payment_processor.is_active = 0 for SDD payment processor type and then update the extension directory path by navigating to Administer >> System Settings >> Directories
2. Update the extension directory path in civicrm_setting table where name = extensionsDir (make sure you serialize the data correctly)
3. Over-ride the extension directory path in civicrm.settings.php

   $civicrm_setting['Directory Preferences']['extensionsDir'] = 'xxx/sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/';

and then update the directory path by navigating to Administer >> System Settings >> Directories

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: I tried #1 and I get some errors after resetting path . Should I restore to older backup where I did not do reset path which led me to Fatal Error: (the first error listed in title) and then try the #1 ?

Comment: Please update the extension path in Directories and Resource URL and then visit Extension page and click refresh and also clear CiviCRM cache(make sure you don't click on Reset Path button).

Comment: I followed the above steps
1) Updated the Extension path in Directories and Resource URL                
2) Clicked Refresh on the Extension Page   3) Cleared the civicrm cache but it still gives Unknown extension  error

Comment: Hi @Pradeep, it worked finally, I had missed something probably when I did #1,#2 and #3 mentioned in the previous comment, thanks for your valuable inputs and time!!!

Comment: Check for folder permission and also check if all the active extension are present under the extension directory

Comment: ok thanks, but it's working now and not throwing an error!

Comment: Pheewwww.... Cheerz

Comment: Don't forget to re-enable the payment processors

Comment: The good news is that in Civi 4.7.31+, a missing payment processor will no longer cause a crash.

Comment: Yup. The latest version will handle missing file issue.